# Color is not changing

Tags: android

How do I change the orange color in this picture. I have removed all reference of orange color in my code but it still appears. How do I remove them?

[image]

I previously used orange but now I changed it to cyan but when app is lauched it appears for a second before changing to cyan.

My layout file

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cyan" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:text="TECHNICAL\nENGLISH -I"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
            android:text="ENGINEERING\nPHYSICS I"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:text="ENGINEERING\nCHEMISTRY I"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
            android:text="COMPUTER\nPROGRAMMING"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
            android:text="ENGINEERING\nGRAPHICS"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="445dp"
            android:text="COMPUTER\nPRGRAMMING LAB"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="510dp"
            android:text="ENGINEERING\nPRACTICES LAB"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="575dp"
            android:text="PHYSICS\nCHEMISTRY LAB"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="435dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="565dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SEMESTER I - GPA CALCULATOR"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:text="MATHEMATICS - I"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:text="calculate" 
            android:background="@color/cyand" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


    <color name="cyand">#00FFFF</color>
    <color name="cyan">#CCFFFF</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: You need to give us reduced/simplified versions of your code & markup files to understand what you have done wrong. We can guess but it is not a good way to solve problems.

Comment: Can you uninstall your app, make a reboot of your device/emulator and then try to reproduce the behaviour? It seems like some kind of caching issue. (I asked for details now I'm guessing) Also clear your project before rebuilding.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı That pic I posted is from the eclipse GraphicalLayout itself

Comment: What about the test run in device/emulator? Does it have the same behaviour?

Comment: yea when the app is launched the orange color appears for a second before turning into cyan it may be because I disabled logo and title in action bar only the tabs are visible

Comment: Hmm, I'm out for lunch but one thing I can suggest that create another project and import your source code to that project, build and test it. If the glitch appears again then we can be sure that your code has the bug.